Does there exist a widely-used operator $\boxdot$ such that $(\theta \boxdot \phi)(x) := \theta(x) \circ \phi(x)$?
Let $\forall X,Y : L(X,Y)$ symbolize the set of all linear operators from $X \rightarrow Y$.
Let us have operator-valued functions $\theta : I \rightarrow L(Y,Z)$ and $\phi : I \rightarrow L(X,Y)$.
It should be obvious that $\forall h \in I : \theta(h)$ is a function $Y \rightarrow Z$ and $\phi(h)$ is a function $X \rightarrow Y$, and that $\theta(h) \circ \phi(h)$ is a function $X \rightarrow Z$.
It also should be obvious that, given these definitions of $\theta$ and $\phi$, $(\theta \circ \phi)$ is not well-defined and subsequently, $\theta(h) \circ \phi(h) \neq (\theta \circ \phi)(h)$.
Let us have a function $\psi : I \rightarrow L(X,Z)$ defined such that $\forall h \in I :\psi(h) :=  \theta(h) \circ \phi(h)$.
One can see that because $\theta(h) \circ \phi(h) \neq (\theta \circ \phi)(h) \Leftrightarrow \psi \neq (\theta \circ \phi)$, the composition operator is insufficient to have a (in programmer lingo) "point-free" expression of $\psi$ that mentions $\theta$ and $\phi$.
This leads me to my question:
Does there already exist a widely-used notation for a binary operator $\boxdot$ such that $(\theta \boxdot \phi)(h) := \theta(h) \circ \phi(h)$? If so, what is the name of such binary operator?

The notation $\theta \psi$ would be understood from context, there's really only one thing it could mean given the types.

@QiaochuYuan Is there a widely-used name for such an operation? The only relevant thing I've found so far is a ProofWiki article on the "Derivative of Product of Operator-Valued Functions", where their definition of what they call a "Product of Operator-Valued Functions" matches what I am looking for in my post. However, searching this term up on AMS returns results that deal with products in the context of inner products, which is not what I'm looking for.

I'm not aware that anyone has bothered to give it a name but I would just call it the pointwise product or pointwise composition. It's not much different than the pointwise product of scalar functions.

"Widely used", not that I'm aware of. But this can be expressed in combinatory logic as $\mathsf{SB}$. This works because $\mathsf{S}$ is the combinator $(a,b,c,d \mapsto a (b d)(c d))$, and $\mathsf{B}$ is function composition. (I didn't get a better simplification, or a name, from either pointfree.io or Chris Rathman's combinator simplifier.)
I'd probably just use $\circledcirc$ or something though, and explain that it means "pointwise composition".
